# Magento Admin panel takes minutes to load. All other pages < 1 second.

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a really strange issue with my Magento admin panel. I haven't made any code changes in months and now all the sudden the Admin panel is taking about 90-160 seconds to load each page while working perfectly for months before. The non-admin panel pages (product pages) load extremely fast.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your logs and truncate several database tables (please backup first) that contain index logs like:

```
 TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
 TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
 TRUNCATE `index_event`;
 TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
 TRUNCATE `log_url`;
 TRUNCATE `report_event`;
 TRUNCATE `dataflow_batch_import`;
 TRUNCATE `dataflow_batch_export`;
```

That should speed up your magento momentarily. I am thinking your frontend is under cache (depending which server you have) and admin is left uncached as always. That would be my first area to look at and do.

Anther thing is your php memory limits because it takes a lot more to work in admin then frontend. So try checking and increasing those limits.

Comment: I am on a dedicated server with a memory limit of 1024MB and still no luck. The Log tables are fairly empty. Another clue is that at the same time my site failed to be able to "Communicate with the Paypal Gateway". Worked perfectly for months and then just the other day it stopped accepting payments and started running horribly slow in the admin panel. Any more ideas?